# Posts to a group page, by a user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a groups model and within that, want users to be able to make posts. Each post belongs to that certain group as well as the user who made it (And later on, each post will have comments). I thought I'd take the rails tutorial microposts section and just adjust it to fit my model (www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts)

Right now, the form partial is visible on the group#show page but I can't build the posts in the posts_controller without providing a group.id, adding @group = Group.find(params[:id]) in the create action doesn't work and I'm not sure how to build this list of posts off a group.

posts_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @post = @group.posts.build(post_params) #Find way to provide group id
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

    def destroy
    end


  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:body, :user_id, :group_id)
    end
```

post.rb (with the other models has_many :posts)

```
belongs_to :group
belongs_to :user
```

The post_form on group#show

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :post %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Create Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

groups_controller.rb

```
def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @post = @group.posts.build
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :groups do
    resources :follows, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  end
  resources :posts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

I did think that perhaps :posts need to be nested inside :groups resource? This gives a "undefined method `posts_path' " though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest posts inside groups like this:

```
resources :groups do
  ...
  resources :posts, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Run 'rake routes' to see how your routes are named. Your form_for must contain a reference to group, i.e.

```
form_for [@group, @post] do
  ...
end
```

Group id will be available in the params hash as params[:group_id]

Also check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html